# Espresso ViewPager: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.KeyEvent.getAction()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I have a Activity with a ViewPager, which works fine when I use the app normally. However, when I use it Espresso (JUnit4, activity launched using ActivityTestRule) I get this error whenever I try to call viewPager.getAdapter():

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.KeyEvent.getAction()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.executeKeyEvent(ViewPager.java:2575)
```

Nowhere in the stacktrace does it mention getAdapter() but the crash happens the exact moment I call it.

If I pause in the debugger for sometime, then I get this crash instead:

```
E/BaseApplication(21357): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No fake drag in progress. Call beginFakeDrag first.
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.fakeDragBy(ViewPager.java:2417)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at com.my.app.ui.common.PagerSlidingTabStrip$1.onGlobalLayout(PagerSlidingTabStrip.java:223)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:912)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1881)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    E/BaseApplication(21357):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I have animations disabled from the Developer Options

Answer (score 0):

In the project `build.gradle` `dependencies` section updating from `com.android.support:support-v13` version `22.0.0` to version `22.2.0` fixed it

Comment: Can you please update this answer? What did you change?

Comment: @JaredBurrows is that better?

Comment: The latest is `22.2.1`.